# Java annotation to mark a function argument should be thread-safe

Tags: java, java-8

Let's say I have a function signature as follows -

```
class CustomerStore {
    public void processCustomerInfo(final BiConsumer<Integer, CustomerInfo.V> consumer) throws Exception
}
```

`consumer` is executed in parallel threads inside `processCustomerInfo`.

Can someone let me know is there any annotation we should be adding to denote that passed in `consumer` should be threadsafe (other than comments)?

For example, the below caller code is not quite correct.

```
final Map<Integer, CustomerInfo.V> cust = new HashMap<>(); // Should be ConcurrentHashMap
fdbCustomerStore.processCustomerInfo((cid, v) -> cust.put(cid, v));
```

Comment: You can create custom annotation. There is no such annotation atm.

Comment: May be [this](https://dzone.com/articles/documenting-thread-safety) will help.